# How to loop a Maven execution?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, sharding

On a maven project, on process-test-resources phase I set up the database schemas with sql-maven-plugin. On this project that are N database shards which I set up with N repeated  with exactly the same content bar the database name. Everything works as expected.

Problem here is that with a growing number of shards the number of similar  blocks grows, which is cumbersome and makes maintenance annoying (since, per definition, all of those databases are literally the same). I would like to be able to define a "list" of database names and let sql-maven-plugin run once for each, without having to define the whole block many times.

I'm not looking for changes in the test setup as I positively want to setup as many shards as needed on the test environment. I need solely some "maven sugar" for conveniently define the over which values the executions should "loop".

I understand that **maven itself does not support iteration by itself** and am looking for alternatives or ideas of how to better achieve this. Things that come to my mind are:

- Using/writing a "loop" plugin that manages the multiple parameterized executions
- Extending sql-maven-plugin to support my use case
- ???

Does anyone has a better/cleaner solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As explained in my reply to khmarbaise's answer, I wasn't really into antrun, but as this seems to be widely accepted I'm starting to think that I should give this possibility some love.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would recommend to use the maven-antrun-plugin to handle this situation, but of course it also possible to implement a particular maven plugin for this kind of purpose.

Comment: For me, personally, to use ant was the least desired solution. I can't really give a better argument to support this than "isn't pure maven".  In the end I ended up writing a very simple fork of maven sql plugin to support exactly that and has been working on production for some months now. For the record, if this happens to be of interest to anyone, the code is here: https://github.com/jkliff/sql-sharded-maven-plugin and I would very much appreciate any criticism/suggestions, since this was actually very quickly done.